# sql query and sum the items

Tags: sql

I am a newbie to SQL complex queries. I mainly know the basics. I am also new to VB.net. Here is my problem:

I have my two tables namely **table1** and **table2**:

**table1**:

```
item_name         quantity        
1. ball-pen        10 pcs
2. bond-paper      20 rms
```

**table 2**:

```
item_name        requested_item      office_name_requested
1. ball-pen           5                  office1
2. bond-paper         3                  office1/office2/office3
```

I want an output that sums all the individual items in **table 1** with all items requested in **table 2**, while automatically subtracting the items left in **table 1**. Here is an example:

**consolidated table**:

```
item_name        itemsleft      items_requested    office_name
1. bond-paper        17                 3             office1
2. ball-pen          5                  5             office2
```

, or maybe there are many offices requested to purchased ball-pen, like this:

```
3. ball-pen          0                  10            office1/2/4/5 depending on how many offices requested the specific item..
```

Comment: You should take the time to read the [Basics of SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: You should also read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a tutorial site - you are expected to demonstrate *some* effort to solve your own problem

Comment: sorry.. i thougt you can help me..if you do not know please say no..if you know then guide me

Comment: I shall guide you to [SQL Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/) where you can *learn* more about SQL.  I also invite you (again) to read [ask] and take the [tour] so you can learn how SO works and how to ask a good question.  More info in the [help].  This is not a tutorial site, mentoring program or guidance center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little breakdown to help you get started since you have not provided any detail to what you have tried (I usually only do this once for new people). I declared a few temp tables so I can populate them with data. Also there are a few other ways to get what you need as well, but not important. Also you did not mention what DBMS you are using; `sql`, `MySql` etc... On a last note, I would consider looking at primary keys, foreign keys, index's etc, currently the only way to join is by the `item_name`. It would be better to join on an `id` of some sort...

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(item_name VARCHAR(25), quantity int)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE(item_name VARCHAR(25), requested_item INT, office_name_requested VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO @table1(item_name,quantity)
SELECT
    'ballpen',
    10

UNION
    SELECT
       'bond paper',
       20

INSERT INTO @table2(item_name,requested_item,office_name_requested)
SELECT
    'ballpen',
    5,
    'office1'

UNION
    SELECT
       'bond paper',
       3,
       'office1/office2/office3'
SELECT
    t1.item_name,
    (t1.quantity - t2.requested_item) AS itemsleft,
    t2.requested_item AS items_requested,
    t2.office_name_requested AS office_name
FROM @table1 t1
INNER JOIN @table2 t2
    ON t2.item_name = t1.item_name
```

Here is the ***output*** of this query...

[image]